# image inline in RichTextBox in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I read rtf file from system. and load to richtextbox.

richTextBox1.LoadFile(@"C:\Users\cpsinghal\Desktop\newt.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);

In this rtf has image also. but richtextbox is not display image properly. image inline is bed.

I found image tag in richtextbox.rtf is **{\pict\wmetafil.........}**

and i add ***{\dn20*{\pict\wmetafil.........}*}*** and save as .rtf in system. then image is inline. [image]

but richtextbox is not showing image inline.

is any other option or can i extend richtextbox.

please guide me.